# SPservices get Values from calculated column

Tags: list, caml-query, calculated-column, spservices

I'm using spservices in SharePoint 2010 to get items from a list, and a want to retrieve all items from this year but i don't get anything.
This **Year** column is a calculated type from the **created** column

```
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "{list guid}", 
            viewName: "{view guid}",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Year' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Calculated'>2016</Value></Eq></Where>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                            var liHtml =$(this).attr("ows_Title");
                            var Year += $(this).attr("ows_Year");
                        });

                }
        });
```

I test this with a different type of column and its working fine, If you can help me a really appreciate

Comment: Is Year column return data type is number or text?

Comment: Single line of text, must be number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CAML query the Value Type you have specified is 'Calculated'. However, it should be the resulting Type of that calculated column.
So, if the resulting value is `Single line of Text`, it should be `Text`, if its a `Number`, it should be `Number`.
You need to change your `CamlQuery` line of code to below:

```
        CAMLQuery: "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Text'>2016</Value></Eq></Where>",
```

Refer [this](https://sptalks.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/query-on-calculated-field-problem/) blog where the blogger faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `<FieldRef Name='Ano' />` in view fields, If you are using in filter...

Also check what is value of status and response xml in completefunc.

Comment: but, how to extract the final value from the calculatedcolumn field and assign it to a string ?